# Advice on a faster SAS code

Tags: sas

I have a data set, call it training, that I need the prediction of column Y using X. The conditional probability distribution of Y given X is in a different look up table and it is a Table distribution according to SAS terminology. The space of X and Y are both {1,2,...44}. The probability lookup table is 44 x 44.

Suppose my probability look up table is

```
x  p1     p2               ...                p44  
1  0.001  0.004            ...                0.0078
2  0.0045                  ...                0.000
..                         ...                ... 
44 0.00089                 ...                0.00067
```

The conditional probabilities are highly skewed. And my training data has a large N.

I am looking for an efficient, high speed way of matching and retrieving the conditional probabilities to give prediction of y in the training data. I am looking at hash to speed up the process and may be some other sampling method besides RAND('table', of p1-p44) to possibily make the program run faster?

below is a mock hash program for this task.

```
data prediction;
array prob[44] _temporary_;

if _n_ =1 then do;
if 0 then set work.prob_lookup;
dcl hash lookup(dataset:'work.prob_lookup');
look.definekey('x');
look.definedata('p1',...,'p44'); /* Is there a wildcard method to specify variable p1 to p44?
look.definedone();
end;


set work.training;
rc = lookup.find();
if rc = 0 then do;
    y_predict =rand('table', p1-p44);
output;
end;
run;
```

The training data table for prediction has a large N, about 2k+, but should also allow more when the probability lookup table is applied for prediction. The probability lookup table is 44*44, relatively small, but highly skewed.

Help on building a faster code for this task is much appreciated. Also if there's an easy way to do it in R, it will be appreciated as well.

Comment: Why a HASH object? What is wrong with just joining the probability table with the new data table on the X variable?

Comment: Right. Then how do you put the values in p1...p44 into the RAND function as the specification for probability distribution?

Comment: Just call it?  Here is example call straight from documentation. `x=RAND('TABLE', p1, p2, ...)` so if your variables are P1-P44 then you could call it with `y_predict=rand('table',of p1-p44)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what HASH adds to this problem.

```
data prediction;
   merge training prob_lookup;
   by x;
   y_predict=rand('table',of p1-p44);
run;
```

I guess it might save having to sort your training set by X?  But if your X values are just integers between 1 and 44 then why not just use POINT= option?

```
data prediction;
   set training ;
   pointer=x;
   if pointer in (1:44) then do;
     set prob_lookup point=pointer ;
     y_predict=rand('table',of p1-p44);
   end;
   else call missing(y_predict,of p1-p44);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! I definitely over complicated this for a code that works! But if my training table has a large N, and actually p1 -p44 makes a highly skewed distribution and it is a lots sampling. Any thoughts on speeding on the step?